# Hilbert Nullstellensatz and ring of continuous functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is there any relation between Hilbert's Nullstellensatz and the fact that the maximal ideals in $\mathcal C([0,1])$ correspond to a point in $[0,1]$ (which can be generalized to compact hausdorff spaces)?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "relation." There's certainly an analogy between the two results; depending on which one you think of as more intuitive you should think of one of them as motivating the other (although curiously the history of these results don't have anything to do with each other, as I recall).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz you mean here that there is a bijection between the maximal ideals of $k[T_1,\dotsc,T_d]$ and the points in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Well I don't think that we can prove one of these theorems from the other one, but we can put them into the same framework as follows.

Let $X$ be a locally ringed space. Then there is a canonical morphism $i_X : X \to \mathrm{Spec}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$, see EGA I, §1.6. It maps a point $x \in X$ to the prime ideal $\{f \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) : f_x \in \mathfrak{m}_x\}$.

If $X$ is an affine scheme, then $i_X$ is an isomorphism. If $X$ is an affine variety in the classical sense (only closed points and everything is defined over an algebraically closed field), then $i_X$ restricts to a  homeomorphism $X \cong \mathrm{Spm}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ (the maximal ideals); this is Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

If $X$ is a topological space equipped with its sheaf of continuous functions to $\mathbb{R}$, then $i_X(x)=\{f : X \to \mathbb{R} : f(x)=0\}$ is a maximal ideal of $X$ (the quotient is $\mathbb{R}$). If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then $i_X$ restricts to a homeomorphism $X \cong \mathrm{Spm}(C(X,\mathbb{R}))$. I doubt that we can reduce this non-trivial result to something more algebraic. For example, injectivity uses Urysohn's Lemma, and for surjectivity we need a special property of $\mathbb{R}$, namely that $u_1^2 + \dotsc + u_n^2=0$ has only the trivial solution $u_1=\dotsc=u_n=0$. Let me recall the proof: If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal and $i_X(x) \neq \mathfrak{m}$ for all $x$, we find $f_x \in \mathfrak{m}$ with $f_x(x) \neq 0$. Since $X$ is compact, there are finitely many $x$ such that $X$ is covered by the open subsets $\{f_x \neq 0\}$. But then $\sum_x f_x^2 \in \mathfrak{m}$ vanishes nowhere, i.e. it is a unit, contradiction.